# Display code dynamically in wp footer based on value in db

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin to display real estate data. I need to display a certain snippet of code in the wordpress footer when a certain value is found in the db. Specifics. I already have the footer code displaying using the following function:

```
// Adds Tucson Association of Realtors required board html to wp_footer()    
dynamically.
function wwidx_footer_script() { ?>
<div class="aztarfooter" style="text-align:center;">©2016 Tucson Association of Realtors. All rights reserved. All information deemed reliable, but Not Guaranteed. IDX information is provided exclusively for consumers' personal, non-commercial use and may not be used for any purpose other than to identify prospective properties consumers may be interested in purchasing.<br> <br><img src="https://www.weeboweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/tarlogo.gif"><br><img src="https://www.weeboweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/EHO-logo-e1494994377845.jpeg"> <img src="https://www.weeboweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/MLS_Clear-1-e1494994488609.jpg"></div>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wwidx_footer_script' );
```

This function displays the code exactly where and almost how I want. The problem is that I need to make it dynamic. In my DB, there is a table called `wp_realty_controlpanel`. In that table, there is a field called `controlpanel_masterdb_user`. When the value in that table is `"wwidx_az_tar"` I want the code to display, otherwise not. You can see the snippet exactly where I want it here [**Link**](http://demo.weeboweb.com/).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function wwidx_footer_script() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "realty_controlpanel";
    $results = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT controlpanel_masterdb_user FROM $table_name WHERE controlpanel_masterdb_user = 'wwidx_az_tar' " );
    if( $results->controlpanel_masterdb_user == "wwidx_az_tar" ){ ?>
        <div class="aztarfooter" style="text-align:center;">©2016 Tucson Association of Realtors. All rights reserved. All information deemed reliable, but Not Guaranteed. IDX information is provided exclusively for consumers' personal, non-commercial use and may not be used for any purpose other than to identify prospective properties consumers may be interested in purchasing.<br> <br><img src="https://www.weeboweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/tarlogo.gif"><br><img src="https://www.weeboweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/EHO-logo-e1494994377845.jpeg"> <img src="https://www.weeboweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/MLS_Clear-1-e1494994488609.jpg"></div>
<?php 
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wwidx_footer_script' );
```

Would you please try above code?

Comment: This was a winner. Thank you so much! I gave you an upvote but my score isn't high enough for it to display yet.

Comment: @DominicGiusti If this answer would be helpful to you then please mark it as approved so it could be helpful for others.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the help!